# Converting mysql table to string

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for the best way to convert data from MySQL table to a string using PHP so it can be kept in a single table cell and so that string can easily be converted back to structured data again using PHP. I am not sure what would be better - XML or JSON, or if there is any better ways to do that.
Thanks

Comment: Just tried doing it via json. Making a json string with json_encode seems to be fine but when I try to return saved string to the browser via ajax its not treating it as json (not an ajax issue, if i send any other data via json_encode it works fine). I noticed when it creates json string it is in square brackets although any other json encoded data sent via ajax doesnt have any square brackets - can that be an issue?

Comment: I had a similar problem, but solution was trivial:  It needed to be wrapped it in an extra pair of braces or something.  I prefer JSON over XML because it is much closer to most languages I work with, and it is more concise.

Comment: I just noticed that its returning text with backslashes added to all quotes .I keep created json text in a single cell of another table, text stored in that cell doesnt have  any backslashes. I use mysqli query and fetch_assoc to get that json text from the table.

Comment: You have to escape things as you feed them to mysqli_query.  The escape characters go away in the table and do not come back upon SELECTing.

Comment: Rick - Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, using real_escape_string and it replaces quotes with &quot  witch remains on SELECTing. I will try replacing &quot with normal quote char and see how it goes, but, ideally, there should be the way to make it work without it.

Comment: I tried replacing &quote; with ' " ' in selected data using string_replace and it works fine, I am getting proper json. But still would be grate to find the way to do it without any string_replace.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to join strings form a mysql data row:

```
    // array containing data
       $array = array(
          "name" => "John",
          "surname" => "Doe",
          "email" => "j.doe@intelligence.gov"
       );


   // implode keys of $array with '=' sign
   $string = implode("=", array_keys($array));
```

and to again seperate this

```
$string_array = explode("=", $string);
```